# LLDB GUI in swift REPL

Tags: swift, lldb

swift command line tool path:

```
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

When I using swift in shell like python interpreter, I found a option `gui`

```
>:gui
```

It look like this:

[image: lldb gui]

Anybody who knowns how to debub a REPL program using it in swift?

By the way, Is there some way to using gui LLDB to debug my iOS app in xcode? I try to pause my app and type `gui` or `:gui` but it can't works.

Comment: Watch the [Introduction to LLDB and the Swift REPL](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) presentation at WWDC, it covers advanced usage of LLDB with Swift

Comment: I have no idea way you want gui mode when Xcode is available

Answer (score 1):

The "gui" mode won't run in Xcode since the Xcode debugger console is not a true terminal.  Not entirely sure why you would want it in Xcode, anyway.

The problem with debugging swift code in the REPL is that lldb isn't currently generating debug information in this mode.  So the debugger has no symbolic information to work with.